# Can't Set Local Origin For OBJMTLLoader Object in Scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a scene using Three.js where I can move objects around. I used the OBJMTLLoader to load in the objects. However, these objects don't have a local origin, they still store their original origins. When I go to move an object, the object first moves back to its original origin, and then you can move the object from there. I have found lots of examples of using centroids and bounding boxes, but I always get that something is undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
loader.load('example.obj', 'example.mtl', function (object) {
            object.position.y = -50; // I want this to be the new origin of the object
            object.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
        });
```

And then my code to move the object:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( (event.clientX - container.offsetLeft) / container.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( (event.clientY - container.offsetTop ) / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    if (SELECTED) {
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
        SELECTED.position.copy(intersects[0].point.sub(offset));
        return;
    }

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {
            INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
            plane.position.copy(INTERSECTED.position);
            plane.lookAt(camera.position);
            updateLightPosition();
        }
        container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
        INTERSECTED = null;
        container.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1).unproject(camera);
    raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    if (selectingTargetPos) {
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(background);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            selectedObject.light.target = new THREE.Object3D();
            selectedObject.light.target.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
            selectedObject.light.target.updateMatrixWorld();
            selectingTargetPos = false;
            container.style.cursor = 'auto';
        }
    } else if (selectingTargetObj) {
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            selectedObject.light.target = intersects[0].object;
            selectedObject.light.target.updateMatrixWorld();
            selectingTargetObj = false;
            container.style.cursor = 'auto';
        }
    } else {
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            SELECTED = intersects[0].object.userData.rootObject;
            selectedObject = SELECTED;
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
            offset.copy(intersects[0].point).sub(plane.position);
            container.style.cursor = 'move';
        }
    }
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    SELECTED = null;
    container.style.cursor = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: iirc some obj exporters put the locations in the vertices and not in the object scenenode position. is that what you mean that 'original origins'? i think i ended up exporting them differently to get them normally, with object origin within the object. are you exporting the files yourself or get from somewhere? live example (e.g. jsfiddle) with the objects & behaviour would help anyone to answer.

Comment: I have a designer that created the models for me. I had him export the models from the origin point in Maya. Moving the objects once placed in the scene causes them to always go back to the point where they are exported at, no matter where in the scene they are.

Comment: perhaps your moving code has a bug? hard to tell just by reading. what you describe sounds impossible in the sense that certainly setting an object position always moves it too .. so for example if you test with object.position.set(N, 0, 0) with values of N=0, N=10, N=100, N=300, N=1000 .. I'm pretty sure the object always moves to different position, and not where it was exported.

Comment: Yes. So if I placed the object at (100, 0, 0) that works fine. If I move it to (100, 100, 0) that works fine. However, once I move it from that location, the object will go back to (100, 0, 0) before I can then move it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the object position is based off of the plane and the objects are grouped, the problem lies in the `INTERSECTED` block of the `onDocumentMouseMove()` event.

This does not get triggered because the raycaster is not recursively checking the objects array. By changing the `intersectObjects()` function to have a second parameter of true, the problem will be solved.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {
        INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
        plane.position.copy(INTERSECTED.position);
        plane.lookAt(camera.position);
        updateLightPosition();
    }
    container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
} else {
    INTERSECTED = null;
    container.style.cursor = 'auto';
}
```